# I have kubernetes cluster. How much will it cost to download files from external sources (outside of the cluster)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I failed to find a resource on google regarding pricing regarding downloading files.
I plan to deploy a pod that will download files for me once in a while and saves it to a bucket.
the files will come from an external source to be exact via UDP connection (outside of google services)

P.s
Will google naturally let me do that or I need some special preparation for that.

Comment: this question is not related to kubernetes, but GCP pricing, which is available here, under network pricing (download is egress): https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing

Comment: @suren hi. thanks for pointing out the right keyword this is very helpful.
do you know maybe specifically at the table what i should be looking at?

Comment: There is too few indication about your architecture. What price do you want to take into account? This one of the cluster? of your pod? when the file is received, is it stored? On persistent disk? On cloud storage? What type of loadbalancer will you use? In which region are you?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere price for downloading a file, outbound traffic to an external source which can be anywhere.  I saw on the price list that it's based on regions.
Once the download is finished it will be stored in a bucket.
Do i need to setup loadbalancer for this?

Comment: Data transfer to your GKE cluster from the Internet ("ingress") is free. Data transfer from your GKE cluster is called "egress". Depending on the region your GKE cluster is running and the location of your Cloud Storage bucket, you might have no bandwidth charges, or up to about $0.12 per GB. Review the Compute Engine Network Pricing for egress network traffic.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, man. Post this an answer so i could vote for it.

Answer (score 1):

Data transfer to your GKE cluster from the Internet ("ingress") is free. Data transfer from your GKE cluster is called "egress". Depending on the region your GKE cluster is running and the location of your Cloud Storage bucket, you might have no bandwidth charges, or up to about $0.12 per GB.

Review the Compute Engine Network Pricing for egress network traffic.

[Network Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing)